# Featured site white-space is very small

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stackexchange.com, featured-site

There is no white-space between the logo and the text:

[image]

It would look better with 10px padding on the left:

[image]

Comment: When did it become blue?? Skeptics background was always black... (guess that when changing the logo, they also made it bit larger)

Comment: @ShadowWizard they got the LESS update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've given the skeptics logo a bit of breathing room.

It was complaining it was getting cramped there, though I think it actually gained some width.

With you shortly...